# How to retrieve Mobile number from Address book iOS

Tags: ios, search, addressbook

I have got every person's name and email and I want to retrieve person's mobile number based on these two variables. I don't want to retrieve every person's mobile number(along with name and email). Just for the one on which user taps. How can I achieve that?

Comment: [ABPerson Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople) & [Address Book Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html)

Comment: I have done all that. Now That I have every person's name and email I should be able to retrieve particular person's mobile number(On which user taps).

Comment: You are able to. So what are you waiting for?

Comment: Basically I want to search address book using name and email and retrieve the mobile number of particular person that matches.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for fetching the specific contact mobile number based on the first name and email id....

```
NSMutableString *contactNumber = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
for(int i=0; i<nPeople; i++)
{
    ABRecordRef person=CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, i);

    NSMutableString *contacName = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [contacName stringByAppendingString:@""];
    [contacName appendFormat:@"%@", (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)];
    ABMultiValueRef emailInfo = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    CFIndex emailCount = ABMultiValueGetCount(emailInfo);
    NSString *emailId;
    if(emailCount > 0)
    {
        emailId = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailInfo, 0);
    }

    if(([contacName isEqualToString:@"<<contatct name>>"]) && ([emailId isEqualToString:@"<<email id>>"]))
    {
        [contactNumber appendFormat:@"%@", (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel)];
        break;
    }
}
CFRelease(people);
CFRelease(addressBook);


NSLog("contact Mobile number %@", contactNumber);
```